# 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project (Visual Studio 2015 update 3) where I am using **Entity framework core** with MySQL. I am able to write to data to my database, but when trying to **query data** using `DbSet<T>.Find(...)` or `FirstOrDefault` I get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContextFactory..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IStateManager,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IConcurrencyDetector,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IChangeDetector)'

I tried to update all the packages from NuGet packages manager, with no success. This question may apear like semi duplicate, but it is NOT, no solution worked for me. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: @Usman, actually it is a little bit a big code, but as I said, the problem comes when the execution hit this line: `return Context.Users.Find(id);` where Users is one of my tables (`DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }`), and Context is an instance of an empty class derived from `DbContext`if you need any specific details I can provide them.

Answer (score 1):

OK it seems to be a bug in **MySQL -> entity framework adapter `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`**. I downgraded from `7.0.6-IR31` to `6.10.1-beta` and everything works fine now!

Comment: is this issue reported?

Comment: @AnonymousCreator no I did not report the issue (neither did not see it reported).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this issue. In Enterprise edition, this issue is not there as of now. 
This bug is still open in community edition. It doesn't support all ef core frameworks versions as of now. Please refer following referenced links for supported versions.

Following is the reported issue.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89855

Following is the version support table.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html